Debian 12.5 Samba share not preserving modification time accessed from MacOS
I've created a Samba share on Debian 12.5. The client is macOS Sonoma 14.5. Files copied to the shared drive are not consistently preserving modification time.
I copy files over, some copy with the correct modification date, some copy with now. Copying a single file, "cp -p" works sometimes. I used Mac "Image Capture" to copy photos from an iPhone. Some times preserve the modification date but most use the current time.
I've found a thread discussing a similar issue but its not clear if there was ever a resolution,
Here's the global portion of my smb.conf file. Its pretty stock.
[global]
min protocol = SMB2

### WINS Support ###
wins support = yes
dns proxy = yes


Well ... the linked to ubuntu bug states that it was fixed - maybe Ubuntu made a change Debian hasan't.
